# How to support iOS 13 with Xcode 10.2.1?

Tags: update, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, mobilepush-ios, xcode

thanks for your new SDK update (v6.3.5)!

Our app is unfortunately not yet supporting Xcode 11. When I attempt building with SFMC 6.3.5, I get this error ":-1: Undefined symbol: ___isPlatformVersionAtLeast".

- Is it possible to build the latest version of the SDK with Xcode 10.2.1?
- Could 6.3.4 still support iOS 13 pushes? (Pushes stopped working on iOS 13 w/ SDK v6.2.2)

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Just to be clear, most of us here aren't directly employed by Salesforce, but rather work with Salesforce as part of our day-to-day jobs. You might find someone else here that has a workaround, but if you're looking for official support then you should probably go through https://help.salesforce.com/support

Comment: @DerekF is right, but some of us monitor the boards and contribute where we can :)

Answer (score 1):

We have discovered a build issue and are correcting the MobilePush SDK iOS version and will be releasing a v6.3.6 *as soon as possible*.

Please check our main docs page at https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/ for updates.

Comment: The update was published and pushed yesterday; the SDK will now build correctly.